# jQuery form submit Scroll to particular error message div

Tags: jquery, forms

Form is long after submit if validation error scroll to first error message div on form submit.

I have tried scrolltop function but it's not useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do something like that:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#YourDiv").offset().top}, 2000);
```

For that this to work you need to know the DIV you want to display.

Comment: i want to scroll up to first error element where error occurred not to particular div 


its working in some cases but not for every case.
i think its may be because of JS conflict

Comment: var firstInvalidElement = $(validator.errorList[0].element);
        $('html,body').scrollTop(firstInvalidElement.offset().top);
        firstInvalidElement.focus();